# Recommendation for HD upgrade of PTZ system

Tags: recommendation

We are using an indoor video recording setup currently based on three Sony D70 cameras, controlled with a Sony RM-BR300 remote control. The three cameras are then mixed with a DataVideo SE-500. The mixed signal is recorded on an iMac using an Elgato video capture S-Video to USB device.

We would now like to upgrade this system to be HD and have been in contact with several suppliers that have made offers based on different brands and solutions.

The offers we got differs in price and brands, so I am looking looking for recommendations about which equipment to get, based on what we are trying to achieve:

- 1080p
- remote controlled (PTZ)
- digital signal "all the way" - meaning no conversions between formats loosing quality like the current system going between S-Video and BNC
- ideally more precision in the camera control than the current system

This is no professional setup, so the price has to be considering that, up to $20000 would be within range.

Since we already have an iMac, I have been looking into Blackmagic Design ATEM for the video mixing instead of using a dedicated hardware mixer, thinking that might save some money. But hardware controls are probably easier to operate.

Offers so far based on cameras (varies a lot in price):

- Dahua SD42212I-HC
- IP HD Avigilon
- Panasonic AW-HE40SKEJ
- Panasonic AW-HE130KEJ
- Sony SRG-300SEW